# mangling name in C

Tags: c, name-mangling

From my memory, mangling name is not used in C, which is kinda of a feature that we take advantage using C function for ABI (Application Binary Interface). But recently I have been reading this article about mangling name in C

https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/name-mangling-in-c/

Question here is, If in any case that compiler will mangle C function name?

Comment: Your question is answered in the blog you have linked to; so what don't you understand?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune That should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since C is a programming language that does not support name function overloading, it does no name mangling. But for compilers targeted at Microsoft Windows Platform, which has a variety of calling conventions like _cdecl,_stdcall etc. the function names are mangled to provide information regarding the calling convention.

For example,

```
 int _stdcall fun(int myVar) {return 0;}
 int _fastcall fun(int myVar){return 1;}
 int _cdecl fun(int myVar){return 2;}
```

the compiler(32-bit) output will be like this:

```
 _fun@4  /* _(function_name)@(argument_size_in_bytes) */
 @fun@4 /* @(function_name)@(argument_size_in_bytes) */
 _fun /* _(function_name) */
```

Answer (score -1):

Function names won't be mangled, except apparently in the case of Unicode identifiers. For example:

```
// Mangled as "o_u03ba" using Intel's compiler "icc").
extern int o\u03ba(void);
```

The issue with `icc` highlighted by the blog article linked in the question is obviously a problem when the compiler generates non-unique symbol names:

```
//Both will have the same symbol name.
extern void o\u03ba(volatile int *p)
{
    *p = -32767;
}

extern void o_u03ba(volatile int *p)
{
    *p = 0;
}

...

volatile int n;

// Should print -32767; may print 0 or -32767.
o\u03ba(&n);
printf("%d\n", n);

// Should print 0; will print the same thing as the previous line.
o_u03ba(&n);
printf("%d\n", n);
```

Functions declared with the `static` keyword have internal linkage. Despite this, the compiler's internal representation may still use a mangled name, though you will never see it in the resulting program. When resolving references to functions, however, the code presented by the article indicates that even using the name at all can cause an issue:

```
static void foo\u03ba(volatile int n)
{
    printf("foo\\u03ba: n = %d\n", n);
}

static void foo_u03ba(volatile int n)
{
    printf("foo_u03ba: n = %d\n", n);
}

...

volatile int n = 10;

// These two lines may print the same thing.
foo\u03ba(n);
foo_u03ba(n);
```

Since you technically cannot take the address of a function and print it reliably, the best you can do is uniquely identify which function is called.

Comment: What you print as approximate address of function is actually the address of the stack

Comment: @Dani I wasn't thinking when I did it. Edited.

Comment: I'm not sure the edit has improved things.  Now you print the value of the parameter, not the address of the parameter on the stack or the address of the function.  On most machines, you could get away with `printf("%s: %p\n", __func__, (void *)foo\u03ba);` as on most machine the size of a function pointer is the same as the size of an object pointer.  However, that isn't formally guaranteed by the C standard (nor by POSIX, except that `dlsym()` has to work for functions and it returns `void *`).  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_   You'll need to make a decision about the degree to which you want theoretical perfect portability vs pragmatic 'works in practice on machines we use at the moment and can currently foresee using' portability.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The clarity comes from the subtle difference in the output. `foo\u03ba: 10` will be printed in the case of `foo\u03ba` being called, and `foo_u03ba: 10` will be printed in the case of `foo_u03ba` being called. `gcc` has no trouble with this (both functions are called), but `icc` will encounter an issue (only one function will be called due to the mangling scheme it uses). That said, I agree that most compilers will happily work fine with a construct such as `printf("%p\n", (void *)foo\u03ba);` and your point is consequently valid.